# File Transfer using WCF Service from One Client To Another Client

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have created a Chat Application using a WCF service. I need a File Transfer Module that can transfer large files in the range of 4-6 GB .

Can anyone suggest an approach for how I might go about doing something like that?

Comment: Can you show some code what you have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the few links to start with

http://garfoot.com/blog/2008/06/transferring-large-files-using-wcf/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37057/File-Transfer-using-WCF-and-Socket

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP